# Make the function return 0 and store it in a variable

Tags: php

Seems super trivial, but can't find a solution to this specific case on SO

A function may return a value of 0 OR another number, which I then want to store in a variable `$s` to calculate stuff. But can't find a clean way of doing it.

So for example:

```
function f() {
    $v = "0";
    return $v;
}

if($s = f() !== false) {
    echo $s;
    // ^ I want 0, but the value above is 1 (since it's true)
}
```

I tried returning it as a string

return "0" instead of a digit, but it doesn't work.

If I do this it will not evaluate to true so nothing will happen

```
if($s = f()) {
   // returns nothing
}
```

But when I `var_dump(f())`, it does show **string '0' (length=1)**

So I can do

```
if(var_dump(f()) == 0)
```

OR

```
if(f() == 0)
```

But is there not a cleaner way to do it, so the function may return 0 or another number and I can just capture it in a variable?

Comment: Did you want `if (($s = f()) !== false)` ?

Comment: damn it.. thank you! Feel so dumb now. Can you post this as an answer, I ran into this a few times before and I think others will find this useful

Comment: @RobertSinclair this is what almost all php developer feels :D

Comment: amen brotha, i'll bookmark this. Have ran into this a few times when querying tables

Comment: I don't think it's specific to PHP. I think all languages would do that due to operator precedence (comparison is higher than assignment usually). `bool b = 3 == 5;` would almost always never compare `b = 3` to `5` unless you specifically told it to with parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parentheses:

```
if (($s = f()) !== false) {
```

Otherwise you're computing the value `f() !== false` and assigning it to `$s`, instead of assigning `f()` to `$s` and then comparing to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

First

```
if($s = f() !== false) {
echo $s;
// ^ I want 0, but the value above is 1 (since it's true)
}
```

Whats happening here is return value of f() is strictly compared to false, that is, "0" is compared to false. They are not strictly equal, hence f() !== false returns true, which is stored in $s as 1.

Next,

```
if($s = f()) {
// returns nothing
}
```

This doesnt enter the if block because $s contains "0" and it is loosely equal to false.

Next

```
if(var_dump(f()) == 0) or if(f() == 0)
```

this works because it is loosely comparing "0" to 0 which is true. Hence it enters the block.

Remember, if condition does loose comparision or == and === does strict comparision. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp).

So, this should work in your case

```
if(($s = f()) !== 0)
```

if f() returns integers

Comment: Thanks man, great explanation, accepted the other answer since he posted working code first. But appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try some parenthesis:

```
if(($s = f()) !== false) {
```

To force `$s` to equal `f()`, not `f() !== false`